# Shade-Plugin-built multimodule application - Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, multi-module, maven-shade-plugin

I have application which is doing some business staff, and presents the outcome through REST api.
Outcome of the build should be one, executable jar, which is later transformed into dockerfile.

Recently, I've been trying to separate its parts into maven modules.
I've split the application (which works just fine when built and run in IDE), assembled the jar using maven-shade-plugin, but when I try to run app using java -jar command I receive following error:

`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

I've already tried using @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation and extending main class with SpringBootServletInitializer - with no effect.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Master POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-backend</artifactId>
    <version>latest</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>app-api</module>
        <module>app-webapi</module>
        <module>app-applogic</module>
        <module>app-deployment</module>
        <module>app-legacydbadapter</module>
        <module>app-integrationtests</module>
    </modules>

    <name>app-backend</name>
    <description>Backend part for app Application</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>

        <axon.version>3.2.2</axon.version>
        <swagger.version>2.8.0</swagger.version>
        <guava.version>25.1-jre</guava.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.5</gson.version>
        <junit.version>5.2.0</junit.version>
        <assertj.version>3.9.1</assertj.version>
        <restassured.version>3.1.0</restassured.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Configuration*</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*Startup*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>coverage-check</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>checkCodeCoverage</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.0</version>
                        <configuration>

                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <rules>
                                        <rule>
                                            <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                            <limits>
                                                <limit>
                                                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                                    <minimum>0.85</minimum>
                                                </limit>
                                            </limits>
                                        </rule>
                                    </rules>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Axon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${axon.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-test</artifactId>
            <version>${axon.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${restassured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Executable module's POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>app-backend</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>latest</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>app-webapi</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Internal dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-applogic</artifactId>
            <version>latest</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-legacydbadapter</artifactId>
            <version>latest</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-api</artifactId>
            <version>latest</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Deployment module's POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>app-backend</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>latest</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <artifactId>app-deployment</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <docker.maven.plugin.version>1.3.6</docker.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven.dependency.plugin.version>3.1.1</maven.dependency.plugin.version>
        <docker.image.artifacts>${project.build.directory}/docker-artifacts</docker.image.artifacts>
        <sonar.jacoco.report.path>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.report.path>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.company.app.webapi.Application</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <outputDirectory>${docker.image.artifacts}</outputDirectory>
                            <outputFile>app-backend-latest.jar</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>docker.company.com/app-backend</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-webapi</artifactId>
            <version>latest</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**App's main class**

```
package com.company.app.webapi;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Configuration class**

```
package com.company.app.webapi.config;

import com.company.app.applogic.config.AxonConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@Configuration
@Import({AxonConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.app")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.app.legacydbadapter")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.company.app.legacydbadapter.model")
@EnableScheduling
public class ApplicationConfiguration {}
```

Comment: check your jar build with all dependency

Comment: Don't use the shade plugin. Spring Boot requires a specific format and already provides an executable jar. Trying to shoehorn shade in the mix won't work and will at least complicate things. Work with the framework instead of against the framework.